# Having to manually define number of datepickers in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails, datepicker

So I have a working form in my Grails app where there are 4 instances of `<td><g:textField id="datepicker" .../></td>` but I've had to manually define the id's as

```
...
<td><g:textField id="datepicker1" .../></td>
...
<td><g:textField id="datepicker2" .../></td>
...
<td><g:textField id="datepicker3" .../></td>
...
<td><g:textField id="datepicker4" .../></td>
...
```

With the head of the HTML (in my GSP) containing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker3").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker4").datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Is there a way I can do this where I don't have to pre-define how many datepickers there are on the page, assign the `datepicker#` to each, and it just pops the calendar up no matter which date text box I click on?

Doing just one `#datepicker` in the head and trying to use `<td><g:textField id="datepicker" .../></td>` on each does not currently work.

Comment: use class instead, ie. `class="datepicker"` to each and in jquery `$(".datepicker").datepicker();`

Comment: Viola! Thank you very much! Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pass ID add a class or data attribute to identify the elements

```
<td><g:textField class="datepicker" .../></td>
<td><g:textField class="datepicker" .../></td>
```

or

```
<td><g:textField data-datepicker .../></td>
<td><g:textField data-datepicker .../></td>
```

and then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker(); //searchs all elements with class datepicker

        //or

        $("[data-datepicker]").datepicker(); //searchs for all elements with attribute data-datepicker
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I prefer data attributes to avoid CSS class collisions